# How do i pass values through razor in mvc4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having a difficult time with Razor and how it passes values back to my controller.

I have the following code

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="inline-toggle">
        <label for="autoreload">Yes or No? <a href="#"><img class="smallInfo" src="/sites/dev-demo/mobile/assets/images/info@2x.png"></a>:</label>
        <select name="autoreload" class="togglehidden" id="autoreload" data-role="slider" data-hidden-id="#autohidden">
            <option value=@(Model.IsTrue = false)>No</option>
            <option value=@(Model.IsTrue = true)>Yes</option>
        </select>
        <div id="autohidden" class="hide">
<input type="text" name="thevalue" id="value" value="@Model.TheValue" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, it's a toggle and when I toggle Yes, I want the value of true to be passed back, if it is no I want the value of false to be passed back to my model. In addition, I have an textbox where I can enter any value which I would like to passback to my Model.Would someone be able to help me with this syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Create a form, perhaps use a strongly typed model and ASP.NET (not razor) will automatically fill your model with the appropriate values.

Comment: I don't think `Model.IsTrue = false` is what you want.  That will set the value of `Model.IsTrue` to false instead of checking what the value is.  Also, I don't think you want a conditional there.  It would be easier if you always set the value to `true` or `false`, however, you may want to change the value of `checked` or `selected` based on `Model.IsTrue`.  You also don't need the placeholder, and hiding it with `display:none` will cause it not to be posted.  Try using a hiddenfield for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a form if you want to make this work. You can choose between a standard or an AJAX form, but I'll stick to standard for clarity purposes.

something like this:

```
@using(html.BeginForm("MyAction", "SomeController")){
 <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="inline-toggle">
        <label for="autoreload">Yes or No? <a href="#"><img class="smallInfo" src="/sites/dev-demo/mobile/assets/images/info@2x.png"></a>:</label>
        <select name="autoreload" class="togglehidden" id="autoreload" data-role="slider" data-hidden-id="#autohidden">
            <option value=@(Model.IsTrue = false)>No</option>
            <option value=@(Model.IsTrue = true)>Yes</option>
        </select>
        <div id="autohidden" class="hide">
          <input type="text" name="thevalue" id="value" value="@Model.TheValue" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

And in your controller

```
public class SomeController : Controller {
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection form){
  var toggle = form["autoreload"];
  var thevalue = form["value"];
 }
}
```

Or you create a custom class

```
public class MyModel {
 public bool AutoReload {get; set;}
 public string TheValue {get; set;}
}
```

And use it in your view

```
@model MyModel
    @using(html.BeginForm("MyAction", "SomeController")){
     <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="inline-toggle">
            <label for="autoreload">Yes or No? <a href="#"><img class="smallInfo" src="/sites/dev-demo/mobile/assets/images/info@2x.png"></a>:</label>
            // without razor syntax
            <select name="autoreload" class="togglehidden" id="autoreload" data-role="slider" data-hidden-id="#autohidden">
                <option value=@(Model.IsTrue = false)>No</option>
                <option value=@(Model.IsTrue = true)>Yes</option>
            </select>
            <div id="autohidden" class="hide">
              @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TheValue) // with razor syntax
            </div>
        </div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

And structure your controller as such:

```
public class SomeController : Controller {
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model){
  var toggle = model.AutoReload;
  var thevalue = model.TheValue;
 }
}
```

This is all C#/ASP.NET MVC 4 101 though, you can find a lot of information on this. I recommend checking out [these](http://www.asp.net/mvc) videos!

Comment: Now I have all of this actually, other than the @using(html.BeginForm) and the input type = submit line, as there is a button I click that posts it to the controller. I'm not sure what I'm doing differently above to the second part of your answer..

Comment: Well, do you have a form? You need a form to send the data to the controller.

Comment: isnt the select in itself a form?

Comment: No, it's a form element. Check the generated HTML code: you'll notice there is nothing that connects element to an action.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say AController

```
public class AController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult YourView()
      {
         return View();
      }
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult YourView(boolean autoreload)
      {
         //autoreload
         return View();
      }
}
```

View

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="inline-toggle">
        <label for="autoreload">Yes or No? <a href="#"><img class="smallInfo" src="/sites/dev-demo/mobile/assets/images/info@2x.png"></a>:</label>
       @using(Html.BeginForm("YourView","A",FormMethod.POST)){
        <select name="autoreload" class="togglehidden" id="autoreload" data-role="slider" data-hidden-id="#autohidden">
            <option value=@(Model.IsTrue = false)>No</option>
            <option value=@(Model.IsTrue = true)>Yes</option>
        </select>
           }
        <div id="autohidden" class="hide">
<input type="text" name="thevalue" id="value" value="@Model.TheValue" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

before end of body tag, I assumed you are using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name=autoreload]").change(function(){
     $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
});
</script>
```

I've just written from here without test.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the form or ajax to send value to the server.

HtmlHelpers normally produce something like the following for bools

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="autoReload" />
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="autoReload" />
```

In the case the checkbox is not checked, it will default to false.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool AutoReload {get; set;}
}

....

public ActionResult DoSomething(MyModel model) 
{
    if (model.AutoReload)
        /* do something */
}
```